# Example of very CPU-intensive C function under 5 lines of code

Tags: c

I'm testing a progress indicator in my program, so I'd like to test it against a function that takes a noticeable amount of time (i.e. >5 seconds) to finish.

I tried this:

```
void doLotsOfWork () {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        arc4random()%(int)HUGE;
    }
}
```

But this runs in under 1 second on my i7. Can you suggest even more CPU-intensive operations? The function body should really be no more than 5 lines of code.

Comment: What method are you talking about?

Comment: You could also write down some loops: `for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++){for (int j = 0; j < 1000000; j++){}}`

Comment: @haccks sorry, I meant function. I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: @GuyT that does the job... I was hoping for something more elegant though...

Comment: Just for testing purposes it's good enough, though. In production users probably upload a huge file or something else.. ;)

Comment: @GuyT uploading a large file would tie up the network but not necessarily the CPU. It depends on what resource you want to load up in your testing

Comment: You're right Brandin. I was thinking about uploading a picture and convert it(put a watermark in it or something else), but your answer is right so I give you a plus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a simple loop should do the trick:

```
/* iterate.c */
#include <stdio.h>

int 
main (void)
{
  printf("start\n");

  volatile unsigned long long i;
  for (i = 0; i < 1000000000ULL; ++i);

  printf("stop\n");

  return 0;
}
```

this takes ~2.5 seconds on my system. feel free to increase the amount of iterations to match your timing expectations.

```
$> gcc -o iterate iterate.c
$> time ./iterate
start
stop

real    0m2.763s
user    0m2.758s
sys     0m0.000s
```

short form:

```
void
wait (void)
{
  volatile unsigned long long i;
  for (i = 0; i < 1000000000ULL; ++i);
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised that isn't removed by the optimizations of gcc!

Comment: @alFReDNSH gcc isn't allowed to optimize anything away, because `i` is declared `volatile`.

Answer (score 1):

Just pause the thread/process? No need to do actual work.

In POSIX, call e.g. `usleep(5000000);` to pause for five seconds (see [`usleep()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/usleep) manual page).

Comment: Pausing the thread is not what I'm looking for. I'm specifically looking for a CPU-intensive operation.

Comment: If it's for testing a progress indicator why does it matter wether if the program actually calls usleep or does some lengthy processing ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz: because I might want to report intermediate progress, and I might want to do that on the same thread the function runs on.

Comment: You can do several shorter usleeps in a loop and report intermediate progress in the loop.

Comment: `usleep` doesn't properly emulate real-world scenarios, which is what I'm trying to do. Besides, "the suspension time may be longer than requested due to the scheduling of other activity by the system" ([docs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989799/xsh/usleep.html)), and you don't know what things I might be doing on the side.